# Can I use an ecrypted flash drive on Android?

Tags: encryption, usb-on-the-go, flashdrive

Is it possible to use a flash drive encrypted with LUKS and connected to the phone with an USB OTG cable?

Comment: Yes if 1) your device is rooted and 2) your kernel is built with `CONFIG_DM_CRYPT`. The latter is necessarily true if your device supports FDE. So decrypt and mount the USB OTG using `cryptsetup` or `dmsetup` as you would do on any Linux PC.

Comment: Maybe an app like [EDSLite](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.sovworks.edslite/) or the full [EDS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.eds.android) could be helpful, too – though I'm not sure if they'd work with entire volumes (the app description just speaks of containers, but explicitly mentions LUKS). Nevertheless, root seems indeed needed. And right: [their website](https://sovworks.com/eds/) mentions "Encrypted partitions and devices support" for the full version, root needed.